# nvm command not available in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, software-installation, node.js

I am trying to build a script in in which `nvm` and eventually node will get installed.
I have installed `nvm` with cURL. I see the modifications in the `.profile` or `.bashrc` file (both work) and when typing the `nvm` at the bash prompt, it shows the options available etc.
So nvm works. Manually I can install node, but as soon as I put the `nvm` command in a shell script:

```
nano test.sh

#!/bin/bash
nvm
```

and run it with:

```
chmod 755 test.sh
./test.sh
```

I get:

```
./test.sh: line 2: nvm: command not found
```

If it can't find `nvm`, I don't even have to think of

```
nvm ls-remote
```

or

```
nvm install ...
```

I got Ubuntu 14.04 installed and Bash is my shell.

Comment: I'd print the path in the script before calling nvm and check if it is correct.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

`nvm` command is a shell function declared in `~/.nvm/nvm.sh`.

You may source either of following scripts at the start of yours to make `nvm()` available:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
. ~/.profile
. ~/.bashrc
. $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh  # if installed via Brew
```

Comment: HI, thanks. This makes sense then as nvm is "installed" in ~/.nvm. And is probably just a shell script. What I am missing though is that I can type nvm and get it to work, but when trying the shell scripts in ~/.nvm it doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by `trying the shell scripts in ~/.nvm`?
I explained how to run `nvm` from the shell script above. Is there anything unclear?

Comment: To elaborate my last comment. when I "sudo find / -iname nvm*" I find only things in my ~/.nvm folder. Executing the ~/.nvm/nvm-exec or ~/.nvm/nvm.sh (the only files in ~/.nvm, which turn out to be shell scripts) does not give me nvm, like just typing "nvm" on the command line. So where is the link between nvm and the program.

Comment: Oh.. I guess `nvm` is an `alias` in your shell environment. Please post the output of `which nvm` and this will clear things out.

Comment: Hi webKnjaZ, this does not provide output...

Comment: No output in the terminal where command `nvm` works? Then perhaps you could check `alias | grep nvm`.

Comment: Hi webKnjaZ, this does not provide output... But it looks like it is not an alias. The output of "compgen -a" does not include nvm, however "compgen -c | grep nvm" does. Meaning it is a command, but not an alias.

Comment: I've installed `nvm` locally and made some research.
`nvm` is a shell function declared in `nvm.sh`, so basically you just need to source it with `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` at the beginning of your script (or, as I wrote above, - source `.profile`/`.bashrc`)

Comment: webKnjaZ, you nailed it! I overlooked the fact that I needed to source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh before calling nvm within the test.sh script. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried doing `. ~/.bashrc`, but `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` worked fine

Comment: . ~/.bashrc and source ~/.bashrc don't work. . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh works fine. haven't tried . ~/.profile

Comment: @user137717 Why is `~/.bashrc` not working? Having the same problem.

Comment: Because you have to first add it there, or use bash in interactive mode.

Answer (score 3):

If you installed it via brew on OSX, then you can load the brew sourced script into the script env by sourcing it as it details on the install.

I have this in projects to bootstrap them :

```
brew install nvm
. $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
nvm install
...
```

Answer (score 2):

From all the answers here and in [this related nvm issue](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1290) I created [this script (gist)](https://gist.github.com/karfau/dcf98c6eefc2f2132c160f5c14d2112f) that you can copy or clone (documentation is inlined):

```bsh
# shellcheck shell=sh
# https://gist.github.com/karfau/dcf98c6eefc2f2132c160f5c14d2112f

# needs to be sourced as part of your script
# 1. tries to configure nvm and run `nvm install`
# 2. checks if the node version is correct based on ./.nvmrc (`v` prefix not supported)
# if both doesn't work, exits with code 1 and some helpful messages

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184512/194420
# https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/1290
if [ -f ~/.nvm/nvm.sh ]; then
  echo 'sourcing nvm from ~/.nvm'
  . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
elif command -v brew; then
  # https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#--prefix-formula
  BREW_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix nvm)
  if [ -f "$BREW_PREFIX/nvm.sh" ]; then
    echo "sourcing nvm from brew ($BREW_PREFIX)"
    . $BREW_PREFIX/nvm.sh
  fi
fi

if command -v nvm ; then
  nvm i
else
  echo "WARN: not able to configure nvm"
fi

NODE_VERSION="v$(cat .nvmrc)"
which node
ACTIVE_VERSION=$(node --version)
GLOBAL_NPM=$(which npm || echo "not found on PATH")
# .nvmrc can contain only major or major.minor or full version
# so we replace active version with node version and anything afterwards
# if something is left, it's not a match
if [ "${ACTIVE_VERSION%%$NODE_VERSION*}" ] || [ ! -e "$GLOBAL_NPM" ]; then
  echo "expected node '$NODE_VERSION' and npm on path"
  echo "but was '$ACTIVE_VERSION' and npm:'$GLOBAL_NPM'"
  exit 1
fi
```

Hope it helps
Feedback on the gist or here is welcome.

PS: In the meantime I have updated the gist to use the `NVM_DIR` environment variable instead of the user directory to support custom installation sections added support for calling `nvm use` instead of `nvm install`.

Comment: `NODE_VERSION=$(cat .nvmrc)` this is enough in mac

Comment: @MidhunGS this only works if the `.nvmrc` file contains the whole string as it is output by `node --version`: `v` prefix, major, minor and patch version. But the `nvm` also allows leaving out the `v` prefix, leaving out the patch version and leaving out the minor version.

Answer (score 0):

Small callout on top of answer provided by @webKnjaZ: I had to source shell function for every command to make it work in my bash script. Something like this:

```
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh --version
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh install 4.4.5
```

Comment: it didn't work for me. The following worked for me:
     ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
    nvm --version

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. 
This is what worked for me:

```bash
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/playground# n=$(which node); n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 "$n"/bin/*; sudo cp -r "$n"/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local

root@ubuntu:/usr/src/playground# sudo npm install express
'/usr/src/playground/package.json'
+ express@4.16.2
added 49 packages in 129.186s
```

The above command looks complicated,
but all it's doing is copying whatever version of `node` you have active via `nvm` into the `/usr/local` directory
(where user-installed global files should live on a Linux VPS)
and setting the permissions so that all users can access them.

Comment: Of course, you don’t need to use ``sudo`` when you’re already running as root.

Answer (score 0):

None of this solution solved my problem I had to do this inside my sh file before using nvm

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm --version # this line can be delete
```